# Storing values in list<> and changing them

Tags: c#, list, struct

I have been trying to create a program that allows the user to edit things such as the supply of mp3 players which have a base value stored in the program:

```
public struct MP3_Players
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int MBsize { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Supply { get; set; }
}

MP3_Players player1 = new MP3_Players
{
    ID = 1,
    Make = "GET Technologies .inc",
    Model = "HF 410",
    MBsize = 4096,
    Price = 129.95m,
    Supply = 500
};
MP3_Players player2 = new MP3_Players
{
    ID = 2,
    Make = "Microsoft",
    Model = "SOFT1",
    MBsize = 1028,
    Price = 432.99m,
    Supply = 500
};
MP3_Players player3 = new MP3_Players
{
    ID = 3,
    Make = "PEAR",
    Model = "APPLE3",
    MBsize = 2056,
    Price = 130.00m,
    Supply = 500
};
MP3_Players player4 = new MP3_Players
{
    ID = 4,
    Make = "logitech",
    Model = "DEF0",
    MBsize = 2056,
    Price = 53.35m,
    Supply = 500
};
MP3_Players player5 = new MP3_Players
{
    ID = 5,
    Make = "Sennheiser",
    Model = "HEIS1",
    MBsize = 2056,
    Price = 399.95m,
    Supply = 500
};
```

Now making a method with a list isn't really an issue, I imagine it goes as follows:

```
public static void mutate()
{
    List<MP3_Players> PlayerList = new List<MP3_Players>;
    Playerlist.Add(player1);
    Playerlist.Add(player2);
    Playerlist.Add(player3);
    Playerlist.Add(player4);
    Playerlist.Add(player5);
}
```

My first question is simply a matter of improvement of code, but I suppose many people reading this will understand the problems I'm running into, primarily that player1 is not static, does this mean I will have to individually make every player static or is there an easier way?

The primary issue however lies with my attempts to create a small program to change the Supply, The idea is for a user to enter an ID and then allow them to edit the supply, this went well for me when I was using an array but I am having issues understanding how to use data in a `list<>` and change it(basically trying to reach the values stored in the list from other methods if possible at all).

Comment: Why is `mutate()` marked as  `static`?

Comment: Your struct should probably be a class.

Comment: I would use classes instead of structs. This allows you to easily change existing players: `list[0].Supply = 3;`

Comment: [How to: Update List Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289%28v=office.12%29.aspx)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way would be to initialize the list by

```
List<MP3_Players> PlayerList = new MP3Players[]{
    new MP3_Players()
    {
        ID = 1,
        Make = "GET Technologies .inc",
        Model = "HF 410",
        MBsize = 4096,
        Price = 129.95m,
        Supply = 500
    }, <-- include more instances of MP3_Players here
}.ToList();
```

and furthermore, the indexer `[]` can be used to access the elements in a list very similar to an array.

Comment: Or you could just use a collection initializer: `new List<MP3_Players> { new MP3_Player() { ... }, new MP3_Player() { ... } };`

Comment: I'm gonna need to look into LINQ more!

Comment: In fact, my comment is a bit misleading. Converting the array to a list has nothing to do with Linq; however I consider Linq very useful.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your "list problem" you could use classes and a dictionary:

```
public class MP3_Players
{
    /* ... */
}

public static void mutate()
{
    var PlayerList = new Dictionary<int, MP3_Players>;
    PlayerList.Add(player1.ID, player1);
    PlayerList.Add(player2.ID, player2);
    PlayerList.Add(player3.ID, player3);
    PlayerList.Add(player4.ID, player4);
    PlayerList.Add(player5.ID, player5);
}
```

Then you can access them via their ID and change them:

```
var player = PlayerList[ID];
player.Supply--;
player.Price -= 10;
```

**BUT** to solve your bigger problem of "persistency" you should think of a "data-store" to persist you data, e.g. Entity Framework and a DB.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using collection initializer for inlining the creation of the PlayerList?

Where static is concerned, static method cannot access non static instance members.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create dictionary like other user explain if the ID of the players are **Unique**, if they are not doesn't start this approach. This is requirement of dictionary !

The other way using List.

```
List<MP3_Players> newList = PlayerList.FindAll(x=>x.Model == Apple3);
newList.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Storage = 30);
```

This will return every Player with Model Apple3 and second row will change all the values for Storage.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, Structs are Immutable. This means that they can't be edited. If you wish to make a change to an item, then it needs to be replaced by a totally new item. You can avoid this by using a class.

One problem that I have ran into editing collections in an enumeration is that the collection was modified and the enumeration can no longer continue. This was happening because I was using a foreach loop that evaluates each item in the collection. I avoided it by using for loops and fetching the element from the list using its index and performing my edit there.